# Color polygon based on points' values (geodataframe column)

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out a way to add a heatmap-like effect to my `Polygon` object based on the values of the `Points` inside of it.

My `geodataframe` is as follows:

```
        inv           x          y          PR                 geometry
0   XX-INV-1-1  -44.894916  -17.409755  0.322000    POINT (-44.89492 -17.40975)
1   XX-INV-1-2  -44.892894  -17.409755  0.500000    POINT (-44.89289 -17.40975)
2   XX-INV-1-3  -44.894916  -17.409678  0.885000    POINT (-44.89492 -17.40968)
3   XX-INV-1-4  -44.892894  -17.409878  0.982000    POINT (-44.89289 -17.40988)
4   XX-INV-2-1  -44.893913  -17.411367  0.619905    POINT (-44.89391 -17.41137)
```

each `Point` has its "PR" value and I would like to create a heatmap based on this specific value. I've tried using `kdeplot()` but it only plots the dataframe based on the density of the points inside the map, ignoring the "PR" values. The closest I've got was using `pointplot()` but its not exactly the visual that I'm looking for. Any ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use seaborn.kdeplot with the weights parameter:

```
import shapely
import seaborn as sns
import geopandas as gpd

geoms = ["POINT (-44.89492 -17.40975)", "POINT (-44.89289 -17.40975)", "POINT (-44.89492 -17.40968)",
         "POINT (-44.89289 -17.40988)", "POINT (-44.89391 -17.41137)"]

geoms = [shapely.wkt.loads(x) for x in geoms]
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={"pr":[0.322000, 0.500000, 0.885000, 0.982000, 0.619905]}, geometry=geoms, crs=4326)
```

Without weights:

```
p1 = sns.kdeplot(data=df, x=df.geometry.x, y=df.geometry.y, fill=True, cmap="Blues", levels=100)
```

[image]

With:

```
p2 = sns.kdeplot(data=df, x=df.geometry.x, y=df.geometry.y, weights = df.pr, fill=True, cmap="Reds", levels=100)
```

[image]